# Tabelas com dados de base de dados

Tags: html, banco-de-dados, rolamento, table

Alguém sabe como restringir um certo numero de linhas na tabela, mas ao fazer *scroll* ver o resto dos dados?

Por exemplo, uma empresa que guarda os dados dos clientes na BD e quer ver todos os dados dos clientes numa tabela, mas apenas 10 clientes por página. Só que em vez de ter um botão para mudar dos 10 primeiros clientes para os 10 seguintes, usar *scroll* para isso.

Tipo isto, sem aqueles números, mas sim com um *scroll*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém me pode dizer como se chama isso ou um site que mostre ou então mesmo mostrar o código?

Comment: Você precisa manter o cabeçalho ao fazer o scroll?

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Sim, preciso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse problema de `scroll` na tabela e manter o cabeçalho é bem famoso.

### Primeira solução [`jQuery Scrollable`](https://github.com/farinspace/jquery.tableScroll).

#### Importante, esse plugin carrega toda tabela de uma vez.

Exemplo:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{ 
    $('#thetable').tableScroll({width:500});
});
```

```html
<link href="http://www.farinspace.com/css/jquery.tablescroll.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.farinspace.com/js/jquery.tablescroll.js"></script>

<table id="thetable" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <td>city</td>
      <td>state code</td>
      <td>zip</td>
      <td>latitude</td>
      <td>longitude</td>
      <td>county</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="first">
      <td>Holtsville</td>
      <td>NY</td>
      <td>00501</td>
      <td>40.8152</td>
      <td>-73.0455</td>
      <td>Suffolk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Holtsville</td>
      <td>NY</td>
      <td>00544</td>
      <td>40.8152</td>
      <td>-73.0455</td>
      <td>Suffolk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adjuntas</td>
      <td>PR</td>
      <td>00601</td>
      <td>18.1788</td>
      <td>-66.7516</td>
      <td>Adjuntas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Holtsville</td>
      <td>NY</td>
      <td>00544</td>
      <td>40.8152</td>
      <td>-73.0455</td>
      <td>Suffolk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adjuntas</td>
      <td>PR</td>
      <td>00601</td>
      <td>18.1788</td>
      <td>-66.7516</td>
      <td>Adjuntas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Holtsville</td>
      <td>NY</td>
      <td>00544</td>
      <td>40.8152</td>
      <td>-73.0455</td>
      <td>Suffolk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adjuntas</td>
      <td>PR</td>
      <td>00601</td>
      <td>18.1788</td>
      <td>-66.7516</td>
      <td>Adjuntas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Holtsville</td>
      <td>NY</td>
      <td>00544</td>
      <td>40.8152</td>
      <td>-73.0455</td>
      <td>Suffolk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adjuntas</td>
      <td>PR</td>
      <td>00601</td>
      <td>18.1788</td>
      <td>-66.7516</td>
      <td>Adjuntas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Holtsville</td>
      <td>NY</td>
      <td>00544</td>
      <td>40.8152</td>
      <td>-73.0455</td>
      <td>Suffolk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adjuntas</td>
      <td>PR</td>
      <td>00601</td>
      <td>18.1788</td>
      <td>-66.7516</td>
      <td>Adjuntas</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

-

### Segunda solução [`jQuery DataTables`](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/scroll_y_infinite.html)

#### Com ele é possível carregar por demanda igual sua necessidade atual.

#### Sugestão do <kbd>[Marcus Vinicius](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23593/marcusvinicius)</kbd>

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bScrollInfinite": true, /* você precisa dessa propriedade */
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "sScrollY": "200px"
  } );
});
```

```html
<link href="http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Nº.Feder.</th>
   <th>Clube</th>
   <th>Tipo HCP</th>
   <th>Data Actual</th>
   <th>TipoJogador</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <th>Nº.Feder.</th>
   <th>Clube</th>
   <th>Tipo HCP</th>
   <th>Data Actual</th>
   <th>TipoJogador</th>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>22739</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>HCP EGA</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-10</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>42944</td>
   <td>165-ACGB</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-11</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>23060</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-08</td>
   <td class="center">Sra.AmadorA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>227391</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>HCP EGA</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-10</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>429441</td>
   <td>165-ACGB</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-11</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>230601</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-08</td>
   <td class="center">Sra.AmadorA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>227392</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>HCP EGA</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-10</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>429442</td>
   <td>165-ACGB</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-11</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>230602</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-08</td>
   <td class="center">Sra.AmadorA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>227393</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>HCP EGA</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-10</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>429443</td>
   <td>165-ACGB</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-11</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>230603</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-08</td>
   <td class="center">Sra.AmadorA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>227394</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>HCP EGA</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-10</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>429444</td>
   <td>165-ACGB</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-11</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>230604</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-08</td>
   <td class="center">Sra.AmadorA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>227395</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>HCP EGA</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-10</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>429445</td>
   <td>165-ACGB</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-11</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>230605</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-08</td>
   <td class="center">Sra.AmadorA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>227396</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>HCP EGA</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-10</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>429446</td>
   <td>165-ACGB</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-11</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>230606</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-08</td>
   <td class="center">Sra.AmadorA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>227397</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>HCP EGA</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-10</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>429447</td>
   <td>165-ACGB</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-11</td>
   <td class="center">Amador</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td>230607</td>
   <td>083-Oitavos</td>
   <td>Suspenso</td>
   <td class="center">2015-06-08</td>
   <td class="center">Sra.AmadorA</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Se quiser conhecer os outros parâmetros deste plugin é só dar uma olhada [aqui](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref).

Comment: Não é só isso que ele quer, ele quer carregar linhas dinamicamente na tabela conforme o scroll for ocorrendo. Mais ou menos assim: http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/scroll_y_infinite.html

Comment: @MarcusVinicius Entendi, interessante esse exemplo... não compensa você transformá-lo em resposta já que ele pediu indicação de site ou exemplo?

Comment: Preciso montar um exemplo aqui, mas estou sem tempo. Fique a vontade se quiser.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius Feito :)

Comment: @MaiconCarraro Muito Obrigado isso ajudou imenso. Mas será que podia dizer qual é, no segundo exemplo que deu, o código que dá pesquisa?

Comment: @MaiconCarraro e como faço para por limite na tabela? por exemplo, ao todo são 100 dados como faço para por apenas 10 e depois fazer scroll? Será que é com css diminiur o tamanho da tabela? já agora os dados são diretamente da base de dados

Comment: @BrunoGibellino De acordo com a documentação que eu coloquei no último link ali o limitador de itens é esse atributo `iDisplayLength`

Comment: Sobre a busca da uma procurado por `Search` nesse link da documentação ou [aqui se preferir](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref)